# Runtime Error: Required "name" field not present in project

Tags: runtime-error, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, runtime, dbt

I used `dbt init` to create a profiles.yml in my `.dbt` folder. It looks like this:

```
spring_project:
  outputs:
    dev:
      account: xxx.snowflakecomputing.com
      database: PROD_DWH
      password: password
      role: SYSADMIN
      schema: STG
      threads: 1
      type: snowflake
      user: MYUSERNAME
      warehouse: DEV_XS_WH
  target: dev
```

Then, I created a new folder on my desktop which only contains a `dbt_project.yml` file that has this:

```
config-version: 2
profile: 'spring_project'
```

When I run this from my project folder:

```
dbt run --profiles-dir /Users/myusername/.dbt
```

I get this:

```
08:56:13  Encountered an error while reading the project:
08:56:13    ERROR: Runtime Error
  Required "name" field not present in project

Error encountered in /Users/myusername/Desktop/spring_project/dbt_project.yml

08:56:13  Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Could not run dbt
08:56:13  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 108, in from_args
    config = cls.ConfigType.from_args(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/runtime.py", line 226, in from_args
    project, profile = cls.collect_parts(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/runtime.py", line 209, in collect_parts
    project = partial.render(project_renderer)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/project.py", line 286, in render
    return self.create_project(rendered)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/project.py", line 316, in create_project
    dbt_version = _get_required_version(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/config/project.py", line 228, in _get_required_version
    raise DbtProjectError(
dbt.exceptions.DbtProjectError: Runtime Error
  Required "name" field not present in project

Error encountered in /Users/myusername/Desktop/spring_project/dbt_project.yml

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 129, in main
    results, succeeded = handle_and_check(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 191, in handle_and_check
    task, res = run_from_args(parsed)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/main.py", line 218, in run_from_args
    task = parsed.cls.from_args(args=parsed)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 185, in from_args
    return super().from_args(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/task/base.py", line 114, in from_args
    raise dbt.exceptions.RuntimeException("Could not run dbt") from exc
dbt.exceptions.RuntimeException: Runtime Error
  Could not run dbt
```

Where exactly am I missing the "name" parameter?

Comment: Have you installed the snowflake module via: **pip install dbt-snowflake**?

Comment: yes ofc @Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the same error as you. Based on [dbt docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/name) you need to add a **name** as well to your dbt_project file.

So change this:

```
config-version: 2
profile: 'spring_project'
```

to this:

```
name: testing_dbt
config-version: 2
profile: 'spring_project'
```

You can use whatever name you like there, but adding the name line fixes the error for me.